# Get number of changed rows in a postgres sql or plpgsql function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, sql-function

How can I get a total number of rows that were updated and inserted and deleted in a transaction called by a function?

I can get this information with `pg_recvlogical`. But can the postgres server be configured in any way to return this information with each postgres function that's called (both sql and plpgsql), or would it require a change to every function if it's even possible?

Is there some kind of metadata that the driver is able to pass back along with the actual function results where this can be somehow included? Or would it be possible to write a generic postgres stored procedure that calls functions and adds this information?

Comment: You need to use [get diagnostics](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS)  in your functions and the return those numbers from your function

Comment: Any options for regular sql functions too since diagnostics is just for plpgsql?

Comment: What "regular functions" are you talking about?

Comment: When language of function is sql not plpgsql.